# Linked list deletion causes Free Heap block ........ modified at ....... after it was freed

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, heap-memory

I have a linked list and whenever I try to free the root it causes the error mentioned in the title.

Free Heap block 011B7EF8 modified at 011B7F38 after it was freed.

Here's the code for creation:

```
if (root == NULL) {
    root = (planet_type*)malloc(sizeof(planet_type));
            /* Here I add data to the struct that root points to */
}
```

and for deletion:

```
if (currentPlanet == root) {
    root = currentPlanet->next;
    free(currentPlanet);
}
```

Where currentPlanet is the node that is to be deleted and is passed to the delete function which looks like this:

```
void deletePlanet(planet_type *currentPlanet)
```

If I remove the line "free(currentPlanet)" then the code works.

This isn't the entire code. For nodes after root the program works as expected and the deletion process is identical.

Comment: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend.

Comment: as is `gdb`, it is happy

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem in whatever's calling `deletePlanet`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you delete a node/element/whatever, you point a pointer to the next one before you delete the current one.  Otherwise you will no longer be able to access the next one after you delete the current, because you won't have the original pointer.

Two other things:  use `gdb` and `valgrind`, two of the best tools for all C jobs.